# Find produces an error in case of hidden rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a method for copying certain cells from range. Range is defined by two words on Worksheet.

Here is method:

```
Private Sub copyOptionsToTable(RowToPaste As Integer, OperatingWorksheet As Worksheet)

    Dim OptionsRange As Range
    Dim cell, x
            
    Set OptionsRange = OperatingWorksheet.Range(OperatingWorksheet.Cells.Find( _
    "[OPTIOONS START]").Offset(1, 0), OperatingWorksheet.Cells.Find( _
    "[OPTIOONS END]").Offset(-1, 0))
    
    x = 0
    
    ' Copy - Paste process
    For Each cell In OptionsRange.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) And cell.Value <> "OPT" Then
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("B" & RowToPaste)
                .Offset(x, 0).Value = cell.Offset(0, -20).Value
                .Offset(x, 3).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            End With
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Next cell
    
End Sub
```

Here is example of calling it:

```
Sub 123()

copyOptionsToTable 18, CalculationItemOM1

End Sub
```

I have recently noticed that if rows with words that are defining range are hided, I am getting an error pointing at:

```
Set OptionsRange = OperatingWorksheet.Range(OperatingWorksheet.Cells.Find( _
"[OPTIOONS START]").Offset(1, 0), OperatingWorksheet.Cells.Find( _
"[OPTIOONS END]").Offset(-1, 0))
```

Is there any options to get this working with hidden rows? Preferably without unhiding hidden rows, because then I need to store information about what is hidden and what is not before running this code and then after it is ready get back as it was before its execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got it working with a little bit different approach:

```
  Private Sub copyOptionsToTable(RowToPaste As Integer, OperatingWorksheet As Worksheet)
    
        'On Error Resume Next
    
        Dim OptionsRange As Range
        Dim cell, x
        
        Dim FirstCell As Range
        Dim LastCell As Range
    
        Set FirstCell = Cells.Find(what:="[OPTIOONS START]", LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat _
            :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
            False, SearchFormat:=False)
        Set LastCell = Cells.Find(what:="[OPTIOONS END]", LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat _
            :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
            False, SearchFormat:=False)
                    
        x = 0
        
        ' Copy - Paste process
        For Each cell In OperatingWorksheet.Range(FirstCell.Offset(1, 0), LastCell.Offset(-1, 0)).Cells
            If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) And cell.Value <> "OPT" Then
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TableForOL").Range("B" & RowToPaste)
                    .Offset(x, 0).Value = cell.Offset(0, -20).Value
                    .Offset(x, 3).Value = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                End With
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next cell
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: The key here is to specify the additional parameters of `Range.Find`, specifically `LookIn` and `LookAt`. Another option is to use `Application.Match`. In any case, best practice would be to test that the `Find` succeeded: `If Not FirstCell Is Nothing Then`... `If Not LastCell Is Nothing Then`...

Comment: @BigBen - interesting I'd always though Find just didn't work on Hidden cells.  Seems like the key is to use `lookin:=xlFormulas` and not `xlValues`

Comment: @TimWilliams personally I got an idea from trying `CTRL + F`. I have hided all rows with "search words" and tried to search for one of them by `CTRL + F` with different settings. It worked, so I started to think it should be possible with VBA as well.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `Find` method doesn't work with hidden data. But, you may temporary copy and paste the data (values only) from entire sheet to another sheet which won't contain hidden data and apply `Find` within the new sheet. After performing the search, just delete or clear the new sheet.

Comment: You can use find, see BigBen's comment